# Mysema QueryDSL JPAQuery with rownumber and between And

Tags: jpa-2.0, querydsl

I have dealer details class

```
@Entity    
@Table(name="DEALER_DETAILS")        
public class CenturyThirdLevelEnrollEngagement { 

@Id  
@Column(name="ID")  
private String id;

@Column(name="DEALER_NBR")  
private String dealerNbr; 

@Column(name="REGION")  
private String region;

@Column(name="TRTY_MGR")  
private String territoryManager; 

@Column(name="DISTRIBUTOR")  
private String distributor;

@Column(name="SEL_CNTRCTD_LVL")  
private String contractLevel;
```

I need to query this table for all the available columns and send only records that are between startindex and startindex+pagesize of column ID . (startindex and pagesize parameters will be coming from UI ).

In the docs there is an example like this:

```
query.from(employee)
.list(SQLExpressions.rowNumber()
.over()
.partitionBy(employee.name)
.orderBy(employee.id));
```

But I need to generate the query with between and and windowfunction .

Please help .

Answer (score 0):

Window functions are not supported in JPA queries, you will need to express the query differently.

Comment: Can you please have a look at my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72944572/select-multiple-columns-in-querydsl-jpa-only-if-columns-are-present-in-a-collect