# Select multiple columns in QueryDSL JPA only if columns are present in a Collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I have a list of columns as `List<String> columns`, and I would like to retrieve those columns using queryDSL.

I have this working -

```
   queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager); //where entityManager is a JPA EntityManager
   JPAQuery<?> query = queryFactory.query();
   QEmployee employee= QEmployee.employee;
   List<Tuple> result = query.select(employee.firstName, employee.lastNameemployee.lastName ,employee.age)
                .from(employee)
                .fetch();
```

This works fine in my test. But here I am specifying the column explicitly in the select(..) part. If my List has only firstName and age like

```
List<String> columnList = Arrays.asList("firstName" , "age");
```

then I only want to retrieve those two column from my select(..) part. QueryDSL select part only accepts Expressions, so I tried doing this:

```
 StringExpression[] columnListExpression =  columnList.toArray(new StringExpression[columnList.size()])
```

and then passed columnListExpression  to my select(..) part as shown below,

```
   List<Tuple> result = query.select(columnListExpression)  // doesn't work
                .from(employee)
                .fetch();
```

however I get a Unsupported Operation Exception. I wanted to use queryDSL because that way I can easily construct the Predicate at runtime in a type safe manner. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655014/select-only-specific-column-in-spring-with-querydsl) brushes the topic, but it was 5 years ago and now we have QueryDSL 5.0
How do I select only those columns that are present my List using queryDSL?

Something like this worked:

```
PathBuilder<Employee> entityPath = new PathBuilder<>( Employee  .class, "entity");
List<com.querydsl.core.Tuple> employeeResults = query.select(
entityPath.get(" firstName  ", String.class)
,entityPath.get("age", Integer.class))
.from(entityPath)
.fetch();
```

However, I don't know the columns before hand and need to construct this `select(..)` part dynamically.

Comment: hi, you can send column data type alongside with column name, then you can use entityPath.get

Comment: If `entityPath.get("firstName", String.class)` is valid and working, you can loop through the collection and fetch the field class via reflection. Something like `for (String field : columnList) { selectList.add(entityPath.get(field, Employee.class.getDeclaredField(field).getType())); } query.select(selectList.toArray(new PathBuilder[] {})).from(entityPath).fetch();`